# Mage_Core_Model_Config - need a non-cacheable config

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, cache

I'm using Mage_Core_Model_Config() to store and read some persistent data I need. I use it like this:

```
// init model config
$this->_config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();

// set value
$this->_config->saveConfig($key, $value);

// get value
return Mage::getStoreConfig($key);
```

However, I noticed that even if I set new value, when I get it the data only update every couple of hours, and that's probably due to Magento cache. But I need my data to be immediate and change every couple of minutes.

Since I'm writing an extension I can't just turn the cache off at my clients servers.

So how do I put non-cacheable data in the config? or how do I force magento to drop the cache for a specific key?

If that's not possible, I'd also appreciate alternative suggestions to use something else instead of Mage_Core_Model_Config. All I need is basic key-value persistent storage mechanism.

Thanks!

**Edit:** is custom variables a good choice for me requirements?

Comment: Are you really updating configuration values every few hours or is that any other data you are working with?
If you are updating data, then I suggest you create you own database table(s) to save it there.

Comment: no its not really configuration, I just need a fast and easy to use key-value storage. but I do need it to update every couple of minutes. would you recommend custom variables? or database?

Comment: Better use your own table in the database for this.

Comment: I would agree with Anna, using your own table makes much better sense. There is an option, I have never used, but I have seen it done, Core Variable.  Honestly, I would assume its not what you need, but if you do not want to have a custom table, this MAY offer what you need.

Comment: Thanks Anna, Russell. I ended up using plain files as a (maybe) temporary solution. I consider this solution temporary but if I see it gives me no problems maybe I'll just keep it. its kidna straight-forward and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do I put non-cacheable data in the config? or how do I force magento to drop the cache for a specific key?

You don't. Configuration is someting which changes from time to time, but not every couple of minutes.

As Anna said:

> Are you really updating configuration values every few hours or is that any other data you are working with? If you are updating data, then I suggest you create you own database table(s) to save it there.

The alternative would be to clear the cache after each write, but this doesn't make sense.